# spring access proxied bean from a non bean class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, codahale-metrics

I have the spring bean that uses dropwizard-metrics annotations on its methods to measure some metrics (see #parse method):

```
@Component
public class Consumer extends AbstractConsumer {

  @Autowired
  private EventsService eventsService;

  private ExecutorService executor;

  @PostConstruct
  void init() throws Exception {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    ConsumerEventsHandler consumer = new ConsumerEventsHandler(Arrays.asList("topic1"), this);
    executor.submit(consumer);
  }

  @Timed(name = CONSUMER_BATCH_PARSING_TIME, absolute = true)
  public void parse(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    String val = record.value();
    eventsService.parseToDB(val);
  }
}
```

As you see this bean submits a new task to the executor service, the task is not a bean but it needs a reference to the *Consumer* bean to reuse its logic (see *consumer.parse(record);* call):

```
public class ConsumerEventsHandler implements Runnable {

private Consumer consumer;
private List<String> topics;
protected final KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

public ConsumerEventsHandler(List<String> topics, Consumer consumer) {
    this.topics = topics;
    this.consumer = consumer;
    this.kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        consumer.subscribe(topics);
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                consumer.parse(record);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}

}
```

Here is metrics config (I use 'ryantenney/metrics-spring' lib):

```
@Configuration
@EnableMetrics(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.inq")
public class SsvpApiMetricsConfig extends MetricsConfigurerAdapter {
  @Resource
  private MetricRegistry registry;

  @PostConstruct()
  public void init() {
    configureReporters(registry);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureReporters(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {

    registerReporter(JmxReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry).
       inDomain("com.inq.metrics").build()).start();
  }
}
```

As result, I see that *Consumer* bean is proxied but the *ConsumerEventsHandler* contains reference on the plain bean, cause when it was creating inside *Consumer's* @PostConstruct method through 'new ConsumerEventsHandler(..)' *Consumer* bean wasn't yet proxied, I assume that @PostConstruct is called before proxing things.

The only workaround I see is to get *Consumer* bean ref through ApplicationContext#getBean every time inside #run method instead of storing the ref inside *ConsumerEventsHandler* class variable.
Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a static on your non spring class

```
public class ConsumerEventsHandler implements Runnable {

private static Consumer consumer;
private List<String> topics;
protected final KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

public ConsumerEventsHandler(List<String> topics) {
    this.topics = topics;
    this.kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>();
}

public static setConsumer(Consumer consumer) {
    ConsumerEventsHandler.consumer = consumer;
}
```

Then on your spring side you can have :

```
  @PostConstruct()
  public void init() {
    configureReporters(registry);
    ConsumerEventsHandler.setConsumer(consumer);
  }
```

Comment: hmm workable solution, but I'm not sure of setting beans refs inside configuration code from the design point of view. 
Maybe just use manual metrics declaration instead? Pls comment on this

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack isn't that the whole point of Inversion of Control you wire everything up in the configuration? Seems fine to me.